# Object missing in json object structure response in jersey

Tags: java, json, serialization, jersey-2.0

This is my simplified object structure:

```
@xmlRootelement

ArticleList implements Serializable{

   //ArrayList of articles

}

Article implements Serializable
{

  User user;

  //ArrayList of bids

}

User implements Serializable
{

 //Properties

}


Bid implements Serializable
{

 //Properties


}
```

Funcion headers:

```
@GET
@Path("/article-search")
@Produces( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
public ArticleList articleSearch() {

    //Function code here

}
```

I return ArticleList in jersey function. In the answer I check that exists the object Bids with elements.

The problem is that in response json is not found any element of the object Bids

The example of response:

```
{

    "articles":[
        {
            //Some Props. Here
            "user":{
                 //Some Props. Here
            }
            //Here list of bids is missing. It is verified that the list contains elements
        }
    ]

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add the geters and setters of the Bid array list in the object Article